# Shws exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" when button is clicked

Tags: java, arrays

i am making a memory game. I had it running and it's buttons are flipping if clicked, but when the buttons in the 3rd and 4th rows are clicked, it doesn't flip when and it shows the ff as it's output:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
at Example.actionPerformed(Example.java:104)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

And here is the code of my program

```
//package MemoryGame;

import java.lang.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import static java.util.Collections.*;

public class Example extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

/**
 *
 */
String front[] = {"1.png", "2.jpg", "3.png", "4.png", "5.jpg", "6.png", "7.png", "8.png"};
ImageIcon icons[];

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JButton exitBtn, replayBtn;
private JButton[] gameBtn = new JButton[16];
private ArrayList<Integer> gameList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private int counter = 0;
private int[] btnID = new int[2];
private int[] btnValue = new int[2];

public Example() {
    init();
    panel();
    setArrayListText();
    setTitle("MemoryGame");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(700, 700);
    setVisible(true);
}

public void init() {
    for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++) {
        gameBtn[i] = new JButton();
        gameBtn[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon("back.jpg"));
        gameBtn[i].setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 28));
        gameBtn[i].addActionListener(this);
    }
    exitBtn = new JButton("Exit");
    exitBtn.addActionListener(this);
    replayBtn = new JButton("Replay");
    replayBtn.addActionListener(this);
}

public void panel() {
    Panel gamePnl = new Panel();
    gamePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));
    for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++) {
        gamePnl.add(gameBtn[i]);
    }

    Panel buttonPnl = new Panel();
    buttonPnl.add(replayBtn);
    buttonPnl.add(exitBtn);
    buttonPnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));

    add(gamePnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(buttonPnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

}

public void setArrayListText() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        for (int ii = 1; ii < (gameBtn.length / 2) + 1; ii++) {
            gameList.add(ii);
        }
    }
    shuffle(gameList);

    // ///////////////////
    int newLine = 0;
    for (int a = 0; a < gameList.size(); a++) {
        newLine++;
       // System.out.print(" " + gameList.get(a));
        if (newLine == 4) {
            System.out.println();
            newLine = 0;
        }
    }   
}

public boolean sameValues() {
    if (btnValue[0] == btnValue[1]) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (exitBtn == e.getSource()) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (replayBtn == e.getSource()) {
        new Example();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++) {
        if (gameBtn[i] == e.getSource()) {
           gameBtn[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(front[i]));
            gameBtn[i].setEnabled(false);
            counter++;
            if (counter == 3) {
                if (sameValues()) {
                    gameBtn[btnID[0]].setEnabled(false);
                    gameBtn[btnID[1]].setEnabled(false);
                } else {
                    gameBtn[btnID[0]].setEnabled(true);
                    gameBtn[btnID[0]].setText("");
                    gameBtn[btnID[1]].setEnabled(true);
                    gameBtn[btnID[1]].setText("");
                }
                counter = 1;
            }
            if (counter == 1) {
                btnID[0] = i;
                btnValue[0] = gameList.get(i);
            }
            if (counter == 2) {
                btnID[1] = i;
                btnValue[1] = gameList.get(i);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Example();
}
}
```

Help :(

Comment: Try to show (SSCCE)[http://www.sscce.org/] and which line is line 104

Comment: gameBtn[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(front[i])); //this is line 104

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing array indices in `front` that are out of bounds.

In line 104, where the error is showing up, you have the following:

```
gameBtn[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(front[i]));
```

Although I'm not sure exactly what you're doing with all the variables, in the for loop two lines above it you are iterating to `gameBtn.length`, which is 16, and `front` is only length 8.

So basically, these lines are where the error is occurring:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++) {
    if (gameBtn[i] == e.getSource()) {
       gameBtn[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(front[i]));
```

Again, I'm not sure what the variables represent exactly, but perhaps you want each element of the `front` array to pair with two elements of the `gameBtn` array,

in which case you might try changing

`gameBtn[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(front[i]))`

to

`gameBtn[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon(front[i/2]))`

Also, the only actual exception in the long error you gave was the top line,

`Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8`

Every other line is just an artifact of the call stack.

Comment: It worked but it doesn't flip back when the partner button chosen is wrong, thanks anyways :)